# Publishing events on a calendar to an individual/a specific group/ or all

Tags: datetime, users

Hey I'm new to drupal and trying to create a calendar that users can publish different items to.

there are different roles involved say:
worker,
supervisor, 
manager.

workers are divided into groups.

Are there modules that would allow a supervisor or manager to post an event that 
1) only a single worker could see,
2) that only a group of workers could see,
3) that everyone  could see.

Would user-relationships handle this?

Comment: Content Access worked well until I added Organic groups to my site. Currently content can be published as private or to a group but I'm having issues in displaying the events in a single calendar. I'm currently stuck on trying to display a calendar view that shows all content from the current users groups and all his personal content (on the same calendar view) 
I can get one showing or the other. ie: I can show all the group content without the personal content or the personal content without the group content. Looking to combine the two.

Answer (score 1):

Events are nothing but nodes so you finding for a solution to have node access for a user, user role, or to all will give you the answer

Might the following modules can do this for you

https://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_userreference

https://drupal.org/project/content_access

Comment: Cheers @arpitr I'll look into it.